# function for reversing an array in C (K&R 2nd ed.)

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

Trying to do Exercise 1-19 of K&R 2nd ed., e.g. writing a function to reverse a string. I thought I managed, but the print output looks strange :-) If I use `STRINGSIZE 5` the output is
`Original String: hello
Reversed String: ollehhello`. If I use `STRINGSIZE 6` to keep in mind the `'\0'` string end character and modify the while-loop to `while ((outputString[STRINGSIZE - (i + 2)] = inputString[i]) != '\0')`, then I get `Original String: hello
Reversed String: olleh?hello`, I guess the `?` is some random character coming from a `'\0'` added to the reversed string in the while-loop at position 5; but `hello` is again added. Could anyone explain how come `hello` gets added to the end of `olleh` and how can I get rid of it so that I only get the proper reversed string ?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STRINGSIZE 5

void reverseString (char inputString[], char outputString[]);

int main(void) {
    char stringToReverse[] = "hello";
    char reversedString[STRINGSIZE]; 
    reverseString(stringToReverse, reversedString);
    printf("Original String: %s\nReversed String: %s\n", stringToReverse, reversedString);
}

void reverseString (char inputString[], char outputString[]) {
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while ((outputString[STRINGSIZE - (i + 1)] = inputString[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: You didn't null-terminate the reversed string. Using `printf` on a character array which isn't null-terminated leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: There isn't even room in `reversedString[]` to hold `"hello"`, forwards or reversed.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you, John, I think I implemented the 0-termination with `if (i == (STRINGSIZE)) {
            outputString[STRINGSIZE] = '\0';
            break;
        } ` after the ++i in the while-loop, but the issue was obviously the declaration of the target string size as pointed out by @4386427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll suggest that you change this line:

```
    char reversedString[STRINGSIZE];
```

to

```
char reversedString[strlen(stringToReverse) + 1];  // + 1 to make room for the string termination
```

Then I would do something like:

```
void reverseString (char inputString[], char outputString[]) {
    int i;
    int len = strlen(inputString);
    for(i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        outputString[len-i-1] = inputString[i];
    }
    outputString[len] = '\0';  // Terminate the string
}
```

Comment: Thank you, 4386427, for the answer, the generalization of the function with `strlen(inputString)` instead of `STRINGSIZE ` was also helpful :-)

Comment: Note that this solution depends upon variable length arrays, which weren't in the Standard when K&R was published (hence, not covered in K&R).

Comment: As noted, using `strlen()` to determine the size of `reversedString[]` would not be kosher for the language of K&R2 (it was published in 1989 or thereabouts, just about the time the original version of the standard was finalized; variable length arrays were added to C99, ten years later), there's an easy alternative that would work: `char reversedString[sizeof(stringToReverse)];`.  Note that `sizeof` includes the terminal null too; no need to add 1.

Answer (score 2):

First, the character array `reversedString[]` does not have enough space to store the null terminator of the string `"hello"`. One option is to use a variable length array here:

```
char reversedString[strlen(stringToReverse) + 1];
```

VLAs were introduced in C99, and made optional in C11. As I remember it, K&R does not include coverage of variable length arrays, since even the 2nd edition was published before this.

Another option that would be compatible with C89 is to use the `sizeof` operator:

```
char stringToReverse[] = "hello";
char reversedString[sizeof stringToReverse];
```

Here, the result from the `sizeof` operator is known at compile time, and can be used in the declaration of a fixed size array. This size *includes* space for the null terminator, in contrast to the result from `strlen("hello")`. Note that this would not work with `char *stringToReverse = "hello";`, since then the `sizeof` operator would give the size of a pointer. This also would not work if `stringToReverse` had been passed into a function first, since then the array name would have decayed to a pointer to the first element of `stringToReverse`.

In the `reverseString()` function, the length of `inputString` needs to be determined (since `STRINGSIZE` is no longer being used); this can be done with `strlen()`, or in a loop. Then, critically, the function must be certain to add a null terminator (`\0`) to `outputString[]` before returning. Also note that a `return` statement has been added to the end of `main()` to make this truly C89 compatible:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverseString (char inputString[], char outputString[]);

int main(void) {
    char stringToReverse[] = "hello";
    char reversedString[sizeof stringToReverse];

    reverseString(stringToReverse, reversedString);
    printf("Original String: %s\nReversed String: %s\n",
           stringToReverse, reversedString);

    return 0;
}

void reverseString(char inputString[], char outputString[])
{
    int length = 0;
    int i = 0;

    /* Get inputString length; or use strlen() */
    while (inputString[length] != '\0') {
        ++length;
    }

    /* Copy to outputString[] in reverse */
    while (i < length) {
        outputString[i] = inputString[(length - i) - 1];
        ++i;
    }

    /* Add null terminator */
    outputString[i] = '\0';
}
```